From the shell make menucfg graphic user configuration is not appearing
I recently installed Ubuntu.
Results of sb_release -a :
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS
Release:    24.04
Codename:   noble

Results of uname -a :
Inspiron-3521 6.8.0-41-generic #41-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Fri Aug  2 20:41:06 UTC 2024 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

I tried to configure using make menuconfig , but I'm getting the below error message in the terminal.
make: *** No rule to make target 'menuconfig'.  Stop.

